# App Crashes On Calling Webview Loadurl method inside switch

Tags: android-fragments, android-webview, crash

my app contains a fragment with a webview and a edit text.i have a navigation drawer with 3 choices and use a switch condition to handle selection,on 3 selections i update the same webview with different html files using the foolowing code ..but my app crashes..

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/src/web.html");  //app crashes
            fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WebFragment.TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new WebFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, WebFragment.TAG).commit();
            break;
        case 1:  fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WebFragment.TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new WebFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, WebFragment.TAG).commit();

            break;
        case 2:  fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WebFragment.TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new WebFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, WebFragment.TAG).commit();

            break;

    }
}
```

my logcat logs http://pastebin.com/snbzASTq

please provide a workaround for this

Comment: could you print the stack trace?

Comment: It is printed out by your development environment when the app crashes